# "Declaration of <function> must be compatible with <interface>" in Drupal 8.6.10

Tags: 8, installation, composer

Up until Saturday I had a functioning Drupal 8.6.x instance. The I did

```
composer update
```

and Drupal 8.6.10 was installed. Since then I get the following in my error logs:

> Declaration of Drupal\Core\Template\TwigTransTokenParser::parse(Twig_Token $token) must be compatible with Twig\TokenParser\TokenParserInterface::parse(Twig\Token $token)

and Drush fails with

> Robo\Robo::configureContainer() must be an instance of Robo\Config\Config, instance of Drush\Config\DrushConfig given

I use PHP 7.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.

I did a clean reinstall of Drupal 8.6.10 and the same things occur. I've tried to replace 8.6.10 with 8.6.9 and even 8.6.0 but I still get these errors. If it were Java, I would suspect that the interface and the class had been compiled with different versions of the compiler. But I don't know PHP well enough to know where to start. These errors seem to me to be in core: all my code is under modules/xxx.

Any hints?

Steve

Comment: How did you install Drupal 8 initially?

Comment: I used composer. I don’t remember the precise command because it was over a year ago. The installation has been updated regularly, using composer, ever since.

Comment: Was Twig updated or something to v2? https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/deprecated.html#token-parsers

Comment: No. Twig has not been updated to v2: twig/twig is at 1.x-dev

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report which should be posted and followed on drupal.org. See https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3039408

Comment: It wasn't a bug report when I wrote it, but it did indeed turn out to be a bug. It wasn't off-topic then, but I agree that it should henceforth be followed on drupal.org and not here.

Comment: @leymannx If you "google" this issue, the 1st result is this page so I think it is useful to let it open, or at least visible since it has a working temporarily fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a global issue on this new Twig version 1.38.0.

I can be **temporarily fixed** by downgrading its version using `composer require twig/twig:1.37.1`

You can follow [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3039408) to know when the Twig version can be updated again.